# Replace associated entities

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, xrm

I'm using [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.aspx) for Dynamics 365.

Let's say I have an entity **Movie** and **Tag**. A **Movie** has multiple **Tag**s.

Let's [associate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient.associate.aspx) the tags A & B to the movie X.

```
EntityReferenceCollection tags = new EntityReferenceCollection();
tags.Add(new EntityReference("tag", "A"));
tags.Add(new EntityReference("tag", "B"));
svc.Associate("movie", "X", new Relationship("movie_tag"), tags);
```

Now imagine I need to link new tags

**How can I replace these tags with new ones ?**

Do I have to retreive the already associated tags, [disassociate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient.disassociate.aspx) them one by one, and associate the new ones ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need "retreive the already associated tags, disassociate them <strike>one by one</strike>, and associate the new ones".

Note you disassociate also takes a collection so you remove multiple in a single call.